# Lexicographically order two lists of variables using constraints

Tags: list, prolog, clpfd, lexicographic, b-prolog

I'm trying to implement a lexicographic ordering constraint in BProlog using its CLP(FD).

As far as I can see from the manual BProlog doesn't provide a built-in `lexLeq` constraints (though there exist efficient propagation algorithms for this global constraint), so I'm trying to write my own and express the ordering as the following set of binary constraints:

```
X1 #=< Y1, (X1 #= Y1) #=> (X2 #=< Y2), (X1 #= Y1 #/\ X2 #= Y2) #=> (X3 #=< Y3), ..., (X1 #= Y1 #/\ ... #/\ XN #= YN) #=> (XN+1 #=< #YN+1)
```

To express the `(A1 #/\ A2 #/\ ... #/\ AN) => AN+1` constraint I think I should be able to reify the `Ai`s, so:

```prolog
domain(B, 0, 1),
(X1 #= Y1) #<=> B
```

I then collect the `B`s and to check that the conjunction is valid I simply do:

```prolog
(sum(Bs) #= N) #=> AN+1
```

The idea leads to the following (probably very ugly) code:

```prolog
lexLeq(Xs, Ys) :-
    lexLeq(Xs, [], Ys, []).

lexLeq([X|Xs], [], [Y|Ys], []) :-
    X #=< Y,
    lexLeq(Xs, [X], Ys, [Y]).
lexLeq([X|Xs], [OldX|OldXs], [Y|Ys], [OldY|OldYs]) :-
    makeAndConstr([OldX|OldXs], [OldY|OldYs], X, Y),
    lexLeq(Xs, [X,OldX|OldXs], Ys, [Y, OldY|OldYs]).
lexLeq([], _, [], _).


makeAndConstr(Xs, Ys, X, Y) :-
    length(Xs, N),
    makeAndConstr(Xs, Ys, [], N, X, Y).

makeAndConstr([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], Bs, N, X, Y) :-
    domain(B, 0, 1),
    (X #= Y) #<=> B,
    makeAndConstr(Xs, Ys, [B|Bs], N, X, Y).
makeAndConstr([], [], Bs, N, X, Y) :-
    (sum(Bs) #= N) #=> (X #=< Y).
```

This *partially* works:

```prolog
| ?- domain([A,B,C,D,E,F], 0, 1), lexLeq([A,B,C], [D, E, F]), labeling([A,B,C,$
A = 0
B = 0
C = 0
D = 0
E = 0
F = 0 ?;
A = 0
B = 0
C = 0
D = 1
E = 1
F = 1 ?;
A = 1
B = 1
C = 1
D = 1
E = 1
F = 1 ?;
no
```

as you can see all solutions produced do satisfy the constraint. The problem is that not all valid solutions are produced. It seems like the constraints I've describe also somehow imply that `X1 #>= X2 #>= ... #>= XN` or something like that, so that all variables are either `0` or `1`,
while the above query should return also solutions like `[0,1,0]` vs `[0,1,0]` or `[0,0,0]` vs `[0,1,0]`.

So, is there something wrong with my reasoning or is there a bug in the above definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first clause of `makeAndConstr/6`, you use `X` for two different purposes, which causes the extra failures (same for `Y`).  This renamed code works:

```
makeAndConstr([X1|Xs], [Y1|Ys], Bs, N, X, Y) :-
    domain(B, 0, 1),
    (X1 #= Y1) #<=> B,
    makeAndConstr(Xs, Ys, [B|Bs], N, X, Y).
```

You could have found this by tracing a simple goal that you expected to succeed, e.g. `lexLeq([0,1],[0,1])`.

**Simpler formulation of the lexicographic ordering constraint**

I want to share with you an elegant solution that I was taught many years ago by my former colleague Warwick Harvey. It goes like this:

```
lex_le(Xs, Ys) :-
    lex_le(Xs, Ys, 1).

lex_le([], [], 1).
lex_le([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], IsLe) :-
    IsLe #<=> (X #< Y+RestIsLe),
    lex_le(Xs, Ys, RestIsLe).
```

which is explained by observing that `IsLe` is 1 if

- either `X<Y` (and the value of `RestIsLe` doesn't matter)
- or `X=Y` and `RestIsLe` is 1.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have found a possible, seemingly working, solution:

```prolog
lexLeq([], []).
lexLeq([X|Xs], [Y|Ys]) :-
    X #=< Y,
    domain(B, 0, 1),
    (X #= Y) #<=> B,
    lexLeq(Xs, Ys, [B]).

lexLeq([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], Bs) :-
    length(Bs, N),
    (sum(Bs) #= N) #=> (X #=< Y),

    domain(B, 0, 1),
    (X #= Y) #<=> B,
    lexLeq(Xs, Ys, [B|Bs]).
lexLeq([], [], _).
```

This is also much simpler than the above.

The difference is that in the first solution I created new `B`s for every call to `makeAndConstr`, instead of reusing the same `B` already created.
Though I'm not really sure how this helps in avoid the bug; it should simply be more efficient.